# Kotlin Documentation is missing for google_mobile_ads, flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, google-mobile-ads

I am using [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) for displaying ads in my flutter application. Both (interstitial & banner) are working as expected.

Now I am adding Native Ads, I followed the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/native#android), but the doc is available only for Java, not for Kotlin. So I converted the Java code to Kotlin using android studio.
Here is my Kotlin Code `ReadingNativeAdFactory.kt`

```
package com.mydream.app

import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.NativeAdFactory
import java.util.Map

/**
 * my_native_ad.xml can be found at
 * //github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/tree/master/packages/google_mobile_ads/example/android/app/src/main/res/layout
 */
class ReadingNativeAdFactory(private val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater) : NativeAdFactory {
    public fun createNativeAd(
        nativeAd: NativeAd, customOptions: Map<String, Any>?): NativeAdView  {
        val adView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_native_ad, null) as NativeAdView 
        val headlineView = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ad_headline)
        val bodyView = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ad_body)
        headlineView.text = nativeAd.headline
        bodyView.text = nativeAd.body
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
        adView.bodyView = bodyView
        adView.headlineView = headlineView
        return adView
    }
}
```

`MainActivity.kt` file

```
package com.mydream.app

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin;
import android.view.LayoutInflater

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(GoogleMobileAdsPlugin())
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample", ReadingNativeAdFactory(layoutInflater))
    }

    fun cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine?) {
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample")
    }
}
```

Now when I run my application, I get the below error
[image]

My Questions:
Is there any error with my Kotlin Code?
What I am doing wrong?

Note:
I have added the file available [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/tree/master/packages/google_mobile_ads/example/android/app/src/main/res/layout).

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: have you tried adding the `@Override` tag for the `createNativeAd` function? The same as it is in the Java version? If that doesn't help, it might be because the Java version expects a `Map<String, Object>` and you have `Map<String, Any>` (as you should in kotlin); but it might be that it really wants you to use the java `Object` instead. Check the tag first, and if that doesn't work, the map (but do keep the tag anyway).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that also, but it was throwing error.

Comment: I see the actual difference now, I think, your map is nullable, the error says it expect it to not be. So keep the tag, but remove the `?` from `Map<String, Any>?`. You can keep `Any` from what I can see in the error

Comment: Tried removing `?` and adding `override`, but still having the same issue.

Comment: I just realised that I said `@Override` initially, that is just Java. For Kotlin you need to to `override fun createNativeAd()`. I'm guessing that you already did it like this instead of the one I've mentioned above, but I can't edit the comments from before.

Comment: Agree @Alex.T, I did `override fun createNativeAd()`. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

May be someone else can encounter this issue so answering my own question.

There are two changes needs to be done in order to fix this issue:

1. In `ReadingNativeAdFactory.kt` file I have used `import java.util.Map`, which needs to be replaced with Kotlin's version i.e. `import kotlin.collections.Map`.
2. In `MainActivity.kt` file, replace

```
fun cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine?) {
    GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample")
}
```

with

```
override fun cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample")
}
```